# Remove all text after a certain word

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have data in a database, the rows are like:

```
Ticket #3532 Updated
Ticket #43252 Opened
Ticket #5462 Opened
Ticket #353 Updated
```

on each row, there is text after the word Updated or Opened

I would like to remove this text on every row so it just displays exactly like the above.

I have tried using:

```
strstr($result["notes"], 'Updated', true)
```

For the `Updated` rows, but this returns

```
Ticket #34564
```

and not the word updated

How can i execute this in either PHP or directly in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the update directly in SQL using the `LOCATE()` function to find the first instance of `Updated` or `Opened` in the string, and the `LEFT()` string function to left-truncate it to that position plus the length of the word `Updated` or `Opened`.  There would be a number of ways to handle this with string functions, but this is the first that comes to mind.

```
UPDATE tickets
SET notes = LEFT(notes, LOCATE('Opened', notes) + LENGTH('Opened'))
WHERE notes LIKE '%Opened%';

UPDATE tickets
SET notes = LEFT(notes, LOCATE('Updated', notes) + LENGTH('Updated'))
WHERE notes LIKE '%Updated%';
```

Both `LEFT()` and `LOCATE()` are documented among the [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

[Here is an example (as a `SELECT`)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e4d7)

[And the same example reformulated for the `UPDATE` statements](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3ba7b/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you speak about MySql, you can select something like :

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(myColumn, 'Updated', 1), 'Updated')
```

with a where clause to handle only the rows having 'Updated'.

Answer (score 1):

PHP solution

```
$str = 'Ticket #3532 Updated some text after';
$needle = 'Updated';

$substr = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $needle) + strlen($needle));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL and you created a proper backup of your database, the following query should do the job:

```
UPDATE `yourtable`
SET `yourcolumn` = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`yourcolumn`, 'Updated', 1), 'Updated'),
    'Opened', 1),
    'Opened');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $string = "Ticket #3532 Updated
    Ticket #43252 Opened
    Ticket #5462 Opened
    Ticket #353 Updated";

    echo preg_replace('/(Updated|Opened)/', '', $string);

    //    OR

    $string2 = "Ticket #3532 Updated";

    echo preg_replace('/(Updated|Opened)/', '', $string2);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's a bit kludgy to do this in MySQL since MySQL doesn't support `REGEXP_REPLACE()` or `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`. On the other hand, PHP has a good regex engine and should be able to grab a match fairly easily. A good regex to match might be:

```
/^(Ticket #\d+ (?:Updated|Opened)).*$/
```

And your code might look something like:

```
$new_notes = preg_replace('/^(Ticket #\d+ (?:Updated|Opened).*$/', '$1', $result["notes"]);
```